# Как узнать что поток завершился чтобы запустить onCreate()

Tags: android, java, многопоточность

Доброй ночи! 
Я выполняю расчеты в фоновом режиме и мне необходимо узнать когда они завершились чтобы вызвать их в onCreate().

```
private void mainProcessing() {

    Thread thread = new Thread(null, doBackgroundThreadProcessing,
            "Background");
    thread.start();
}

private Runnable doBackgroundThreadProcessing = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        backgroundThreadProcessing();
    }
};

private void backgroundThreadProcessing() {
    [ ... Трудоемкие операции ... ]
}
```

Comment: а asynctask не подходит?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, чтобы дождаться окончания Thread, есть метод [**join()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29). Попробуйте так:

```
private void mainProcessing() {
   Thread thread = new Thread(null, doBackgroundThreadProcessing,
        "Background");
   thread.start();
   try{
      thread.join();
   }
   catch(InterruptedException e){
   }
}
```

Если есть предположение, что вычисления могут не завершится в отведенное время, впишите параметром к методу join() время ожидания в миллисекундах.

Comment: так-то оно так, но в контексте вопроса - шаг на те же грабли. То есть, UI поток уснёт и система предложит его прибить.

Comment: Как я понял, вопрос именно о том, как узнать о завершении потока.

Comment: А чтобы система не убивала процесс, для ожидания создать отдельный поток:  

    private void mainProcessing() {
  final Thread thread = new Thread(null, doBackgroundThreadProcessing,
    "Background");
  thread.start();
  new Thread() {
   public void run() {
    try {
     thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
   }
  }.start();
 }

Answer (score 0):

Для общения потоков предусмотрен класс `Handler`,
 метод `activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable action)`,
 и готовое решение `AsyncTask`

Если лень переделывать код можно сделать из Вашего следующее:

```
    private void backgroundThreadProcessing() {
        [ ... Трудоемкие операции ... ]

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

    public void run() {
        /*здесь уже UI - поток, вызываем нужные методы*/

    }
});
    }
```